# Share an image and tag some people in a Android App to google plus from inside the code

Tags: java, android, google-plus, share

I'm creating an Android App that shares an image or a text in your google plus profile. I need to tag some people from inside the code with the function -> .setRecipients(recipients). I succeeded to share an image in google plus or share an text tagging some people from inside the code. But i couldn't do both of them, i tryed to share an image and tag people from inside the code, but when i share the image with function addStream(myUri), the function setRecipients(recipients) stop working. If i comment the addStream(), the setRecipients() works fine but don't shares the image. I tryed to change the setType to "video/*, image/*" or "image/jpeg", but nothing. Any suggestions?

```
        ArrayList<Person> recipients = new ArrayList<>();

        recipients.add(PlusShare.createPerson("106189723444098348646","Larry Page"));
        recipients.add(PlusShare.createPerson("109813896768294978296","Sergey Brin"));

        Uri myUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media/10222");

        Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
                .setType("text/plain")
                .setText("Sharing in google plus!")
                .setRecipients(recipients)
                //.addStream(myUri)
                .getIntent();
        startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
```